# Plotly and SQL Server Express compatibility

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, plotly

I'd like to know if the Plotly Database Connector (when doing a SQL Server connection) supports a SQL Server Express edition database.

I tried to connect using the `sa` username and its password but nothing happened. I get the error:

> Failed to connect to [hostname]:[PortNumber] - connect ECONNREFUSED [my IP address]:[PortNumber]

These are my inputs:

- Username: `sa`
- Password: `mypassword`
- Host: `myHost` (SQL Server Express as my instance)
- Port: (I left this port blank)
- Database: myDB

So, it is compatible? Or does it only work with (full) SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I achieved to connect SQL SERVER Express with the Plotly Database Connector, so I hope this answer helps someone in the future!

First of all I asked in its GitHub page and the developer answered with a reference of the same problem and [its solution.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3097#issuecomment-73798671)

Basically you have to search and modify the file named: `connection-manager.js`

Which was located in this directory: `C:\Users\Arturo\AppData\Local\Programs\plotly-database-connector\resources\app\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js` after I installed the Connector in my PC (your path may vary).

Then, you open it, and, in the line 42 you'll see this code (if it isn't in that line just look up for the code) :

```
var connectionConfig = {
      userName: config.username,
      password: config.password,
      server: config.host,
      options: {
        port: config.port,
        database: config.database
        }
```

The problem here is that you have to give it the instance name, so, we will add one line more of code:

```
var connectionConfig = {
      userName: config.username,
      password: config.password,
      server: config.host,
      options: {
        port: config.port,
        database: config.database,
        instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'//this line.
        }
```

And that's it! We save the file and restart our Plotly Database Connector, after doing it we introduce our credentials as usual (without the `\sqlexpress` in the **host** field) and it will work!

**Note:** If you have a text editor like SublimeText, it's easier to find the code that I'm showing, just press `Ctrl+Shift+F` and search by folder, inserting the full path of the Plotly Database Connector.